# How to use 'get' method with foreign key field?

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I have a model with a foreign key field `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` which links to the User model in django.contrib.auth.models. I'd like to do the following:

```
ModelName.objects.get(user.username=request.user.username)
```

I get the following error at the above point in my code:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ModelName.objects.get(user__username=request.user.username)`

Edit: depending on your model relationship, this may result in multiple records, in which case get() would throw an exception, so you could use this instead:
`ModelName.objects.filter(user__username=request.user.username)`

Comment: This worked! I've used that syntax before, but for some reason I couldn't find it or remember it...

Answer (score 1):

Another convenient way to retrieve objects for a specific user is this

```
user = request.user
objs = user.modelname_set.get(pk=x)
```